# Как передать html и script в dataType через Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/ - использую скрол для бесконечной прокрутки
Вторая страница в пагинации, которая подгружается с помощью infinite-scroll содержит такую структуру

```
<div id="vk_post_-000000_00000"></div>
<script> 
(function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) 
return;
 js = d.createElement(s);
 js.id = id; js.src = "//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?121";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
} 
(document, "script", "vk_openapi_js"));
 (function() {
 if (!window.VK || !VK.Widgets || !VK.Widgets.Post || !VK.Widgets.Post("vk_post_-000000_00000", -000000, 00000, "bP1pSeQM_aHgcw7e7GIlW_tsow", {width: 385}))
 setTimeout(arguments.callee, 50); }());
</script>
```

(из этого получается потом iframe :)
Проблема в том что подгружается только ..., а  ...  не хочет брать

В infinite-scroll только два типа dataType  html и json, как сделать чтобы и html и script передавались ?

Comment: вместо многоточий вы ничего не забыли написать?

Comment: а не проще загонять json и уже на стороне клиента собирать HTML?

Comment: @approximatenumber поправил многоточия)

Comment: @Shnur как пример на второй странице пагинации содержиться блок вот с таким кодом (привел в описании в первом посте). Это подключается виджет "записи на стене" пост с контакта, который превращается в iframe. Буду очень признателен за любую помощь как это передать, как передать с помощью того же json